# positive definite matrix inverse

Tags: matrices

\begin{eqnarray}
(A^T W^{-1} A)^{-1}&=^?&(A^T W A)^{-1}
\end{eqnarray}
where **W** is kxk positive definite and  **A** is kx1 vector
If the above is not correct, is there a way to rewrite the equation above? Any inputs?

Comment: Have you tried any non-trivial example?

Comment: No. For $k=1$, $W=[2]$ and $A=[1]$, the identity is already incorrect:$[2]\neq [1/2]$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=x$ conventionally.   Then $x^TW^{-1}x$ is a scalar and hence $$( x^TW^{-1}x)^{-1}= x^TW^{-1}x$$ But also by usual inverse we see that $$( x^TW^{-1}x)^{-1}= ( x^TWx)$$, equating  we get $$W=W^{-1}$$
 Addendum: As can be seen the minimal polynomial for a positive definite involutory matrix can only be $m_W(x)=(x-1)$ which is the minimal polynomial for the Identity matrix.

Comment: The first equation in response does not seem to be correct?

Comment: Inverse of a scalar?

Comment: how can an inverse of a scalar equal to the scalar except for the case of one?